# Known Issues List SharePoint & IE 11

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, ie, ie-11

Is there a definitive known issues list available from a recognised source (i.e. Microsoft) for IE 11 and SharePoint Enterprise and Foundation for 2013, 2010, 2007?

Comment: Is there a specific issue you need to solve?

Answer (score 2):

Well, SP2013 has a IE10 tag, so it seems to be optimized for it. Other issues are very dynamic depending on each Browser and Version I would say.